# how to restart to number theorems and equations in each section

Tags: numbering

I would like to number the theorems in section 5 as "Theorem (5.1)", "Theorem (5.2)" etc.

I would also like to number the equations in section 5 as (5.1), (5.2) etc.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks-
mike

Comment: There are very easy ways to do it, but we need a compilable minimal example to know how your theorem-like structures are defined, which packages you load for that, in short we need to know the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general answer: for theorem-like structures, you need this kind of declarations in your preamble:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

Numbering of structures depending on `thm` will automatically be reset at each new section.

For equations, you can use the `chngcntr` package. The directive

```
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
```

will reset the equation counter at each new section and prefix this counter with the current section counter.

The starred version: `\counterwithin*{equation}{section}` also resets the equation counter but does not prefix it with the section counter (which is not advisable for cross references).